# Defining a function with two parameters

Tags: python, python-3.x, caesar-cipher

Can anybody explain how this piece of code knows the integer value of "shift-val" so it subtracts it from the ASCII value of character

```
alpha=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']


def encodeMessage(message,shift_val):
    encodedMessage = ""
    l = len(alpha)
    length = len(message)
    for i in range(0,length):
        # ord returns ASCII value of character, we add shift_val to it and 
        subtract ASCII value of 'A'
        x = ord(message[i])+shift_val- ord('A')
        # x could exceed 26, we need to cycle back hence mod 26 is used.
        x = x % 26
        # add xth index alphabet to encoded message
        encodedMessage += alpha[x]

# return encodedMessage
    return encodedMessage


def main():
# message will be a string
    message = ""
    UserInput = input("Enter maximum 10 upper-case letters in one line to store: ")
    lengthAlpha= len(alpha)

    while not UserInput.isalpha() or  len(UserInput) > 10 :                # message is not acceptable in case it's greater than ten or it isn't a letter
        print (" No special characters numbers are allowed (maximum 10 letters) ")
        UserInput = input("Enter maximum 10 upper-case letters in one line to store: ")
    else:
    message =UserInput
    message = [element.upper()  for element in message]                                                                          
    move = int(input("How far do you wish to shift?: "))

    print('The encoded message is',encodeMessage(message, move))
main()
```

Comment: That code contains an indentation error (I'm assuming the `return` should be inside the function body), but it looks like `shift_val` is simply passed into the function when it is called. Is that what you're asking about?

Comment: You are right the return should be inside the function body.  ord(message[i]) takes the ASCII value of each character in the message, ord ('A') does the same thing for the list of alpha. What is the numeric value that is being subtracted from it which is defined as shift_val? Sorry if the question sounds bad.

Comment: The value being subtracted from `ord(message[i])` is whatever value is passed into the function as `shift_val`. Presumably that is some numeric value. But there is literally no way to answer this based on what you have provided. Maybe a number is passed in, maybe a string, maybe an arbitrary object, maybe a list or dict, maybe `None`. You need to show us how this is called.

Comment: I've added the other part of the code. I honestly didn't think that part had anything to do with it. My bad sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user is asked for an amount to "shift". This value is stored in a variable called `move` as an integer:

```
move = int(input("How far do you wish to shift?: "))
```

This value is passed into `encode_message()`, where it is bound to the `shift_val` parameter:

```
print('The encoded message is',encodeMessage(message, move))
```

`encodeMessage()` knows the value of `shift_val` because it gets passed into the function as an argument. In another context `shift_val` could have any other value; it depends entirely on how the function is called.

Comment: Thank you @Chris! You are saying that basically, shift-val gets its value from the user input so the function could also be written as;                       
    def encodeMessage(message,move):                                                             
           x = ord(message[i])+move- ord('A')

Comment: @EmreÇakır, only if `move` is somehow set to `int(input("How far do you wish to shift?: "))` in the scope of the function. It still needs to be passed in, e.g. by calling `encodeMessage(message, move)` as you are now. The parameter `move` in the function declaration and the variable `move` outside the function have no relationship; passing the variable into the function when you call it binds its value to the parameter.